# loop through variables java android studio

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and im having a bit of trouble looping through some variables;
I wanted to loop through the four variables and see if there were any repeated variables, then saving the non repeated in a second array or make a count, for example.

```
ValueA = "fred"
ValueB = "apple"
ValueC = "fred"
ValueD = "water"
```

Output `count = 3` or `array={"fred","apple","water"}`

```
     String arr[] = new String[4];

                        arr[0]= valueA;
                        arr[1]= valueB;
                        arr[2]= valueC;
                        arr[3]= valueD;
```

Comment: Store them in a Set and duplicates would disappear.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? There are multiple ways to do this. Create a Set which doesn't allow duplicated; use a Java 8 stream with `.distinct()` to remove duplicated items; etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways in doing this,

- You can store the variables in a Set and get back an Array.

  ```
   String[] withoutDuplicates = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array)).toArray(new String[]{});
  ```
- Loop through first array -> have another empty list -> check before inserting into the second empty list. (You can try this since you are beginner, List already has contains() for you)
- You can use Stream.filter().distinct() from Java 8

  ```
  Arrays.stream(array).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
  ```

I personally prefer the third one! :)

Comment: Just to expand, this assumes that an `equals` method has been correctly implemented for custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 String otherArr[] = new String[4];
 int counter = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i< arr.size(); i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j< arr.size(); j++){
         if( arr[i].equals(arr[j])){
           //two similar variables
           otherArr[counter++] = arr[i];
         }
    }
 }
```

If you have more questions I can send you some decent guides.

Comment: it's missing ';' at the end of otherArr[counter++] = arr[i]

Comment: Should? Try it now.

Comment: It does now, parenthesis missing